# KCFinder not browsing

Tags: php, ckeditor, kcfinder

I am using ckeditor with kcfinder. In my localhost with xampp, I can browse, upload and select any image without any problems. Then I put same project to my server, ckeditor works fine, browse server shows up, even I can upload image but when I click to browse server button, kcfinder layout shown with no response, no content.
[image]

EDIT: It works perfect on Microsoft Edge browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset my browser now it is fine.